# Symfony Console: how to show line number when error/exception/warning occurs

Tags: php, symfony, error-handling, console-application, symfony-console

When running Symfony Console applications and an error/exception/warning occurs, such as:

> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException]
>     Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

it does not show the line number where the problem is, so it's difficult to locate.

Is there a way to show it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution is to run the command using `-v` or `-vv` or `-vvv` option. Those options specify different levels of [verbosity](http://symfony.com/doc/master/console/verbosity.html).